# MSAL Android. AuthenticationActivity finishes but threadpool thread for auth request remains in WAIT state

Tags: java, android, threadpoolexecutor, azure-ad-msal

callback method [3rd param] in acquireToken is not invoked because of a thread WAIT condition.

Interactive authentication. Authentication and authorization succeeds. Valid Redirect URL is returned. **this.finish()** is called in **returnToCaller**:

InteractiveRequest.java:  This method is not invoked after AuthenticationActivity finishes.

```
static synchronized void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    Logger.info(TAG, null, "Received request code is: " + requestCode + "; result code is: " + resultCode);
```

onActivityResult is not invoked and the thread is left in a WAIT state. The callback method passed into **publicClientApplication.acquireToken({three arg overload})** is not invoked. Sample application does not receive notification that authentication flow is complete and does not close sign in activity.

[image: Screen cap from Android Studio debugger showing locked thread pool thread after auth token received]

AuthenticationActivity.java

```
private void returnToCaller(final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    Logger.info(TAG, null, "Return to caller with resultCode: " + resultCode + "; requestId: " + mRequestId);
    data.putExtra(Constants.REQUEST_ID, mRequestId);

    if (null != mUiEventBuilder) {
        Telemetry.getInstance().stopEvent(mTelemetryRequestId, mUiEventBuilder);
    }

    **setResult(resultCode, data);
    this.finish();**
}
```

**Sample app gradle configuration**

- Gradle version 4.4
- Android Plugin version 3.1.0

**Module build.gradle contents**

```
    compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.microsoft.graph.snippets"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath false
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
implementation ('com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:0.1.1'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:25.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'

// Butterknife
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

implementation 'com.microsoft.graph:msgraph-sdk-android:1.1.0'

implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'

implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'

// Test libraries
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2'
```

}

Comment: Have you found a solution?